# Django: Won't Delete Post

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get my posts to delete on the click of a button that pops up on the screen instead of sending the user to a different delete page. The form works but it won't actually delete the posts.

Template

```
    {% block head %}

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/my_posts.css' %}">
        <title>Create - My Posts</title>

        <script>
            function togglePopup(){document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active")}
        </script>

    </head>

    {% endblock head %}


    {% block content %}
    <div class="content_section">
        <div class="btn_container">
            <a class="new_post" href="{% url 'newpost' %}"><button class="new_post_btn">New Post</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content_section_two">
            {% for product in products %}
                <div class="post_short_container">
                    <div class="title_container">
                    
                        <a href="#" class="post_link">
                            <div><b>{{ product.title }}</b></div>
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_btns">
                        <a href="{% url 'editpost' product.id %}" class="edit_link">Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="stats_link">Stats</a>
                        <div class="ad_btn_container">
                            <div class="ad_btn">Ad</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="delete_btn_container">
                            <div class="delete_btn" onclick="togglePopup()">Delete</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="delete_prompt_container" id="popup-1" action="{% url 'deletepost' product.pk %}">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p class="delete_prompt">Are you sure you want to delete this post?</p>
                        <div class="cancel_delete_container">
                            <div class="cancel_button" onclick="togglePopup()">Cancel</div>
                            <input value="Delete" type="submit" name="confirm" class="confirm_delete_button">
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>

    

    {% endblock content %}
```

`views.py`

```py
def deletePost(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myposts'))
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('deletepost/<int:pk>', views.deletePost, name='deletepost'),
]
```

Comment: there is not much to do. an anchor tag, href points to a url-path connecting to a function in backend, needs the posts pk and thene call the delete function for that pk-post

Comment: You have written product.pk, make sure there is not any typing mistake.